# Would it be a good idea to have an introductory YouTube video (with subtitles in many languages) about math.stack?

Tags: discussion

I've thinking about that maybe could be helpful for new users (users that did just start university, know nothing about virtual communities, nothing about MathJax, don't know much english, etc) as an alternative to know about math.stack and to learn say:

First off: the rules,
How to properly ask a question?, How to answer?, How to search?, etc. i.e. How the site works in general?
But all this information, in a video, that is, users could learn by hearing, observing and reading a little. Me thinks this could be more attractive to learn from something; in general a video has background music, animations, etc.
Say you  need to learn something, well you have the book as an option *or* a video with music and animations explaining to you the book content.

Perhaps could be more than 1 video of 5 minutes of lenght? idk

> In summary, when creating an account or when wanting to learn about math.stack, users could choose: 1.*video or 2.reading* to learn about math.stack.

Do you think this might be helpful?

Comment: ah And what is math.stack in first place?

Comment: New users are already expected to read [the Tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour), which provides much of this information.  If they don't do this, what makes you think they will watch a video covering the same ground?

Comment: @XanderHenderson Because it's a video. // But ok, I got the point, let's forget this idea.

Comment: This is not a bad idea.

Comment: Related (although probably only marginally): [Suggestions for examples of well-asked questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20893).

Comment: I never would have watched this video. But I know a teen who's into STEM-y stuff who gets almost all of his information from Youtube videos, so it's possibly a good idea for his generation / learning type. So I think "because it's a video" could actually be a valid response, especially if, as you suggest, you made it engaging with animations and music. (I also think that many of us us who are already active participants on the site are the worst possible judges of whether this could be useful. :--) )

Comment: This reminded me of this video made by Scott Morrison: [Citation prototype for MathOverflow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hrCUjtepj7E). (It is about the original version of [citation helper](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/citation-helper/info) - which was a userscript, only later it was incorporated into the Stack Exchange interface.) I do not know whether there are some other "instructional" videos for MO.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC  Perhaps it couldn't hurt.  But by and large, it seems most users arriving here for the first time to ask a question used Google to search an *immediate question for a pending assignment*, and so tend to ask with that immediate need, and not terribly willing to learn the "ropes" of the site, be it written, or in video.  Even a pop up saying "Hey, watch a you-tube intro to the site!" would be skipped when there's an urgency to get an answer or get help with the question that prompted them to search in the first place.

Comment: @MartinSleziak  Users on MO are not equivalent to first time users led to math.se via a Google Search.  A video might help those who are already committed to stick around, perhaps, but we're still going to face the problem of users coming here for the sole purpose of getting an answer to an assignment.  MO doesn't deal with that, and if some users mistaken MO for a site like math.se, they are readily told to go elsewhere.  They don't have rep seekers looking to enable them there.

Comment: I have no problem with users seeking help with their work, when they are willing to play by the rules, and/or are willing to take suggestions from users and the expansive system of information available to them regarding how to ask a good question.  I do have problems with users who don't want to bother with helping themselves, or cooperating with answerers or adapting to site expectations, insisting only on users here to do their work for them.

Comment: In the context of this question, I thought that it might be worth checking whether there are already some videos about this site. But I did not find much: [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=mathematics+stack+exchange), [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=mathematics+stack+exchange&tbm=vid). Basically, I've seen there a video where some people recorded their conversation in which one of them is explaining to others the basics of Stack Exchange. Other than that, I did not something at least related to the idea proposed here...

Comment: ... One could also check whether there are similar videos about [so]. I will add that nobody is preventing any user to create something like this - if somebody considers such video useful, they might simply create it and mention here on meta. Even if it isn't in the official help, maybe it might be still useful for some people. However, many of us probably do not have the skills or the time (or both) to create such video.

Comment: For people wishing to regularly participate in the site, it is important that such a video be made. It is true that there are users who will skip such a video out of urgency or regarding it unimportant, but then again they can never be facilitated if that is their attitude. We must help those who want to be helped in the first place, and such a video will be helpful , most importantly a basic MathJax tutorial, rules on asking questions (clarifying meaning of context etc.), and the meta site, which is also important. But moderators must be informed before anyone makes a video, because...

Comment: ... we don't want to send wrong messages about the site to new or prospective users, and IMO moderators are the ones that uphold the vision for the site, so will be able to guide prospective video makers on what to put and what not to put on such a video. In fact, the best thing would be for moderators to make the video themselves, although I can understand if they are busy.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC "...you made it engaging with animations and music." huh?

Comment: @Satyendra :) // I thought the community didn't want this. I saw -1,-2,-3 downvotes and then mod Xander comment.. well. But I see different

Comment: Well your post has been upvoted as well. And I really think it is not a bad idea. You have also videos for desmos or geogebra that are really usefull even there are also good tutos why not for MSE.

Comment: @Satyendra exactly, I've also thought that, why  doesn't math.stack has a wonderful YouTube video too?

Comment: @MartinSleziak ok, Thank you Martin.

Comment: People are more into videos now Aliesa.

Comment: Aliesa hahaha:D

Comment: @amWhy Regarding your first comment, but if you let them know about math.stack and then they see: "Hey, watch a you-tube intro to the site!" or "read all" well they might be more interested in the former

Comment: @MartinSleziak "However, many of us probably do not have the skills or the time (or both) to create such video" indeed, I can imagine for sure. I myself couldn't, at least currently. My idea was first to see if the community agree on this, if yes, then to request the video to CMs or alike or to ask permission to them (but you say it's not required) for someone to create it. But then who'll be this someone

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Absolutely. I agree on what you say, however I also thought on the owner of math.stack to be first informed. And yes yes, the video must be made very careful, on what to put and what not to put on such a video

Comment: @allesia_b fully agreed, thank you for the response

Comment: @allesia_b: I was just trying to emphasize that the video should use "background music, animations," if it's going to contribute anything new. The reason I mentioned it is that I've seen many videos (like on /r/programming) where it's just a person reading a wall of text, and the image is that static text. I don't believe that would be useful. So just being a video isn't enough.  But if it were something like a 3blue1brown video, with "background music, animations", yes, that could be helpful. If you've got an inclination I think you should try!

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Aha. Yes of course that's part of the idea of the video: to have effects, music, animations, nice voice explaining, and not speaking too fast like some english videos where it's not easy to follow them, etc. well decorated. A proffesional would know. Another thing to discuss is the content to be included, like what's the fundamental that a new user should learn first. Perhaps just one or two videos for introduction. And then to tell them that they could learn more in others parts on the site, like math.meta

Comment: althoug the speaking form wouldn't matter that much if one just knows the very basic of english