# Is it possible to prevent substitution in approach0?

Tags: support, search

I don't know if the question is well suited here, but I don't know about a forum dedicated to this search engine, yet since it is widely used by MSE members, I guess that should do it (please redirect me, if not).

One of the main advantage of Approach0 is its internal substitution mechanism, so for instance if you search for $f(x,y)$ it will also search for $f(u,v)$ or $f(a,b)$, etc... bringing results that would not have appeared else, which in general is a good thing.

But in some cases, I have found it to be inconvenient, especially when you search for a specific subject.

For instance, it is good for $i$ to be replaced by $n,k,j$ and so on when the subject is about integer algebra, but I would like it not being substituted when it is the complex $i^2=-1$.

The same goes for $z$ complex, I don't want it to be substituted by $x$ and get all inappropriate answers only valid in the real case.

Most of the time, I workaround it by adding keywords in the search (like complex, integer, etc...) but it is not always efficient.

Is there a way to force a literal expression search in Approach0 ? Like escaping characters of some sort ?

---

Edit:

Thanks to Martin Sleziak, effectively the links provided shows a discussion between Wei Zhong and Jykri Lahtonen addressing this very subject.

Here is the quote by W.Z:

> But I do agree it may be beneficial to give options to control what
> level of substitution strictness a specific query wants to apply,
> although technically possible, my preference is still let search
> engine work on its side to prioritize better matches at the same time
> allow more possibilities in results to improve search recall.

Comment: Chatroom [In the search of a question](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46148/in-the-search-of-a-question) might be a resource, as the description says "When you are looking for a specific question (using Approach0 or by other means)".

Comment: I vaguely remember some mentions that Approach Zero gives higher priority to exact matches in the search result, see [this comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12993/what-is-the-best-way-to-search-for-a-math-equation-on-the-internet/24881#comment126878_24881) or [or this message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/46148?m=54533323#54533323). Anyway, Wei Zhong will be able to say more about this.

Comment: Thank you, it pretty much answers my question. I put an addendum above.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Update:* `\exact` queries are supported now.

Example: [`OR content:$\sin\left(\omega \exact t \right)$`](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csin%5Cleft(%5Comega%20%5Cexact%20t%20%5Cright)%24)

---

Currently it is not possible. However, exact symbol matches are supposed to be prioritized to the very top of search results.

As a result, in your complex number example, it should first list as many $i^2 = -1$ as possible before other possibilities such as $n^2 = -1$. However, this gets tricky when you enter a larger expression as query where only small part of that expression is supposed to be exact match. For example, if your query is
$$
z=x+yi
$$
but results like $z=x+ya$ can show up at a higher rank than say $c=a+bi$ simply because search engine does not have enough math semantic knowledge to preserve the meaning of imaginary letter `i`, rather than basic knowledge about syntax structure and a few commutative operators.
In this case, I think we do need to invent a "query language" to specify those symbols you do not want to be replaced. Some thing like `z = x + y \exact{i}` would be desirable. So I agree this is needed.

BTW. What I plan to implement next is also related to query language. I want to add boolean filters to keywords, so that you may be able to query `NOT:$z = x + y \exact{i}$` to exclude any result matches `z = x + y \exact{i}`. I will be investing some time to come up a way to implement these. To get it right and giving my own time constraints, please allow at least a couple of months before I can let this happen.

Thanks for your suggestion. (I have kept this idea in the [project TODO list](https://approach0.xyz/docs/content/en/TODO.html))

Comment: This would be very helpful, indeed! Not sure we can collectively make it worth your while, but have you set up a PayPal account for tokens of appreciation?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and also for all your efforts in making this search engine very valuable.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for asking. Only Github sponsorship is accepted for now. The project is related to my research, so no worry I feel it is a good investment for doing it. The only issue is it may take a while for me to figure it out.

Comment: @zwim Thanks, you are welcome!

Comment: I will add that one example showing the usage of \exact is included in the FAQ post on searching: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265#29267)

Comment: I have taken the liberty to move the “update” to the top of the answer, so that it is more visible.